# gcc 4.8 linker error during linking boost thread library

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, boost, linker-errors

I have compiled boost library myself using g++4.8 compilation finished with success. Everything is located in ~/bin/boost. After compilation all files are located in /Users/$(USER)/bin/boost/stage/lib/

Below necessary make parts:

```
CC=g++-4.8
LD=g++-4.8

BOOST_LIB_PATH=/Users/$(USER)/bin/boost/stage/lib/
BOOST_HEADER_PATH=/Users/$(USER)/bin/boost/

LFLAGS=-L$(BOOST_LIB_PATH) -lboost_thread

release: $(OBJ)
        $(LD) $(OBJ) obj/main.o $(LFLAGS) -o $(RELEASE_NAME)
```

Everything goes ok during compilation but the linking process fail. Basically all errors look the same:

```
ndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
```

I have already read :
[Attempting to use Boost.Filesystem however it doesn't seem to link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079287/attempting-to-use-boost-filesystem-however-it-doesnt-seem-to-link)
[C++ / Boost: Undefined Symbols in example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820269/c-boost-undefined-symbols-in-example)
and many others but still did not find solution.

I have no idea where is problem, i have change the order of linking, i try to link directly thread library but i still get same result.
Problems occur during compilation of https://github.com/dbedla/snake-cpp11 under mac os x 10.8.4 (I have to modify makefile)

I will be grateful for any suggestion how to solve problem.

Sorry for my english :(

Comment: You need to add `-lboost_system` to the linker commmand

Comment: You seem not to have selected an answer for your question. What is missing still? What more can we do for you?

Answer (score 5):

You also need to add `-lboost_system` after where you had `-lboost_thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the boost *system* category, so you need to link against that (libboost_system), too.

```
CC=g++-4.8
LD=g++-4.8

BOOST_LIB_PATH=/Users/$(USER)/bin/boost/stage/lib/
BOOST_HEADER_PATH=/Users/$(USER)/bin/boost/

LFLAGS=-L$(BOOST_LIB_PATH) -lboost_thread -lboost_system

release: $(OBJ)
        $(LD) $(OBJ) obj/main.o $(LFLAGS) -o $(RELEASE_NAME)
```